# При смене компонента с картой с включеным getPanoramaManager().then((manager: any) => manager.enableLookup()) - ломается приложение

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Использую yandex map.
Реализовал фичу getPanoramaManager().then((manager: any) => manager.enableLookup()) на карте (показывает точки панорамы на карте).
Столкнулся с проблемой, если manager.enableLookup() активен, и выключить компонент с картой (например, показывать или скрыть карту), то приложение ломается.
Вопрос, есть ли предохранитель в Яндекс картах для manager.enableLookup() в таком случае или что нужно сделать, чтоб приложение не ломалось?
Пс, пробывал эффектить анмаунт с manager.disableLookup() - не помогло.

Comment: Пожалуйста, соберите минимальный пример на том же jsbin.com или ссылку на страницу приведите, чтобы было понятно, как реализован код и что ломается на странице.